# Как передать файл php-скрипту на сервере?

Tags: скрипт, ajax, php, сервер

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно передать файл для обработки на сервер скрипту при использовании технологии ajax. Файл выбирает пользователь, затем он должен обработаться на сервере. Код вызова серверного скрипта-слушателя:

```
  req =new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        if (req) {  
      req.open("POST", 'http://www.site.ru/admin/?page=handler_load_xls&xls='+xls, 
      true); //скрипт к которому обращаемся
```

Поле файла:

```
<input name="xls" id="xls" type="file" maxlength="255" value="" style="width:230px;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Поле должно быть в форме. У формы должен быть специальный аттрибут. Через JS чистый путь файла не вытащить просто так.

Comment: Спасибо, всё, я уже поняла, с помощью ajax не возможно передать текстовый файл, сделала через невидимый фрейм.

Comment: @masha2, конечно же возможно передать файл и очень легко. Смотрите в сторону [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData). Единственный минус - это кроссбраузерность, Например, IE ниже 10-ой версии, работу с этим объектом не поддерживает.